# IF N=$161^3$-$77^3$-$84^3$.Then,Which of the following statements is not true?

Tags: number-theory

> N=$161^3$-$77^3$-$84^3$,Which of the following statements is not true?

a)N is divisible by $4$ and $23$

b)N is divisible by $23$ and $11$

c)N is divisible by $4$ and $7$

d)N is divisible by $8$ and $11$

**MyApproach**

I calculated $161$/$4$=$1$

$161^2$/$4$=$1$

$161^3$/$4$=$1$

$77^3$=$1$

$84^3$=$0$

So,I got the number to be divisible by $4$

Similarly, I did for other numbers and I got Ans as d) which is not true.

> IS there any other approach through which I can calculate fast?

Comment: Once you know that $161\equiv 1$ mod $4$ then you can just cube 1 instead of working out what $161^3$ is. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @SamWeatherhog No,I wasn't.I thought there would be a pattern after 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* $(a+b)^3-a^3-b^3=3ab(a+b)$. Apply this to $a=77=7\cdot 11$ and $b=84=3\cdot 4 \cdot 7$.

Solution:

> Since $a+b=161$ is odd, $8$ cannot divide $N$. This is enough to answer the question without even worrying about whether $N$ is divisible by $23$.